# Multiple character check in pig script

Tags: apache-pig

I have to check the below condition in pig script. Is there a easy way code the below conditional statement in PIG.

```
if VAR1 == 'A' OR 'B' OR 'C' OR 'D'
   VAR1 = ' ' 
else 
   VAR1 = 'Z'
end if
```

I can use the below statement to achieve this, but is there a easy way to check the below condition.

```
VAR1 = (VAR1 == 'A' OR VAR1 == 'B' VAR1 == OR 'C' OR VAR1 == 'D') ? ' ' : 'Z';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will work for you:

`INDEXOF('ABCD', VAR1) > -1 ? ' ' : 'Z'`

`INDEXOF()` will return -1 if `VAR1` isn't found in the string.